# Spring security and filter chain

Tags: spring, filter, spring-security, csrf

Good morning.
I'm struggling about filterchain and security configuration for spring security

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private CustomHeaderVerificationFilter customHeaderFilter;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .addFilterBefore(customHeaderFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/myapp/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();;

            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the logic will be soemthing like, every call will be filtred by customHeaderFilter, then if the call is from myapp/login as httpGET i will permit and no other authentication will be needed, otherwise...i permit all (reason lie ahead)

```
@Component
public class CustomHeaderVerificationFilter   extends OncePerRequestFilter  {

    @Autowired
    Dao engine;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String headerValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        try {
            if (headerValue != null && calculateMatch(headerValue.split("Bearer:")[1],request.getHeader("realmName"))) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
              throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NullPointerException e2){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write("Errore credenziali errate");
        }
    }

        private boolean calculateMatch(String fromFront,String realmNameHeader) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NullPointerException {
        //prendo la secretdalBack

                String realmSecret = engine.getSecret(realmNameHeader);
                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                String input = realmSecret + ":" + realmNameHeader;
                byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : hashBytes) {
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b);
                    if (hex.length() == 1) {
                        hexString.append('0');
                    }
                    hexString.append(hex);
                }
                String s = hexString.toString();
                return fromFront.equals(hexString.toString());

        }

}
```

(a quite basic filter for non jwt bearer, this is not the issue, i suppose).

nevertheless, every post call i use, i will recive a unauthorize 403 error.
Csrf should be the "problem" and quite all the documentation i found, they just skip it disabling: but i will to master it and integrate in my app.
I did not understood if my POST must be preceded by a GET call to ask a csrf token, or is done in the handshaking part of call.
I test various approach but lot of them utilyze .csrf() and it's deprecated, also whit custom filter who just check the lenght, but for a funny reason, only my get will enter in this filter.
So: where is the error in the flow? i need to check by logic the csrf filter? i must save it as jwt token?

Answer (score 1):

the error you are facing is due to csrf configuration, you need to have csrf token in all your unsafe requests(any request that changes state)

A CSRF attack works because browser requests automatically include all cookies including session cookies. Therefore, if the user is authenticated to the site,
and the user enters an evil website this evil website can send a post request (does whatever) to our website and our site cannot distinguish between legitimate authorized requests and forged authenticated requests.
so we want to give the user a unique token that he can save (away from cookies) and the user uses that token in each unsafe request (ie any request that changes the state)

when and how to get csrf token ?

1- In Spring Security 5, the default behavior is that the CsrfToken will be loaded on every response. so you by default you get an XSRF-TOKEN cookie within each response from the server.

2- In Spring Security 6, the default is that the lookup of the CsrfToken will be deferred until it is needed. so the cookie won't be set unless you send a state changing request (post, put, ...)
you can overcome this and get csrfToken for each request with the following configurations .

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
    http
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        )
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

private static final class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
        csrfToken.getToken();

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

3- also, you can have an endpoint that returns csrf token and you hit it whenever you need. like this

```
@GetMapping("/csrf")
public CsrfToken getCsrfToken(CsrfToken csrf) {
    return csrf;
}
```

all 3 are acceptable solutions.
in the first and second you fetch XSRF-TOKEN from cookies and
in the third you fetch the token from the response body, then use it as X-CSRF-TOKEN header with next unsafe requests.

links that may help :

[cookieToHeader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_defer_loading_csrftoken